# What is the best way to bundle Gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a project with multiple subprojects, many of them have similar dependencies. I want to bundle them, so I just have to write one line in the build.gradle to add multiple dependencies. I tried a version catalog but in such a bundle you can only use dependencies for one gradle methode like "implementation". But I want something like this:

```
bundle "feature" {
 annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
 implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
 implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations")
 runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
 annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
}
```

and then use it in a build.gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
 bundle "feature"
}
```

Should I implement a own plugin or what would be the best aproach for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and simplest way is to create your own precompiled gradle plugin. For this purpose you create a submodule named "buildSrc". You implement a src/main/groovy/{yourpluginname}.gradle in which you define alle dependencies and plugins like you would do in a build.gradle. Then you can use this plugin in you other submodules.
Be aware that buildSrc must be on the first level of oyur root project and should contain a a build.gradle that should look like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and a settings.gradle which can remain empty.

Further information: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins